# ChangePropertyAction behaviour does not work on Popup with a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i have the following window, it has a button, and when i click on it, it shows a popup that contains some text. When the popup is closed, the behaviour cleans the text inside the popup

```
<Window
x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:behaviours="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="300"
Height="300"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="Red"
    Orientation="Vertical">
    <ToggleButton
        x:Name="CustomButton"
        Width="40"
        Height="40"
        Content="Checkbutton" />
    <Popup
        IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=CustomButton, Path=IsChecked}"
        Placement="Bottom"
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CustomButton}"
        StaysOpen="False">
        <behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
            <behaviours:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
                <behaviours:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Text"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UrlTextBox}"
                    Value="" />
            </behaviours:EventTrigger>
        </behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="UrlTextBox"
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Background="Green"
            Foreground="White"
            Text="A url" />
    </Popup>
</StackPanel>
```

Now, if i change the child of the popup to a user control like the following:

```
    <Popup
        IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=CustomButton, Path=IsChecked}"
        Placement="Bottom"
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=CustomButton}"
        StaysOpen="False">
        <behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
            <behaviours:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
                <behaviours:ChangePropertyAction
                    PropertyName="Text"
                    TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CustomControl, Path=UrlTextBox}"
                    Value="" />
            </behaviours:EventTrigger>
        </behaviours:Interaction.Triggers>
        <local:CustomControl x:Name="CustomControl" />
    </Popup>
```

CustomControl:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="WpfTests.CustomControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="800"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<TextBlock
    x:Name="UrlTextBox"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="Green"
    Foreground="White"
    Text="A url" />
```

The behaviour crashes, because it cannot find the property text and i don't know why.
I know i can do this using code behind, but i would like to do it in the xaml.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line isn't going to work

```
TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CustomControl, Path=UrlTextBox}"
```

Because the Path part needs to point to a Property (the TextBlock inside the UserControl is compiled as a public field).

You need to add a line in you UserControl code-behind like this:

```
public TextBlock UrlText => this.UrlTextBox;
```

and then in your behaviour change it to this

```
TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=CustomControl, Path=UrlText}"
```